# Prefixing SCSS code without nesting rule to its child items

Tags: css, import, sass, nested

I'm creating css themes for our framework. I want to prefix all specific CSS rules with class namespace to make it look this way.

```
.my-skin .button {...}
.my-second-skin .button {...}
```

It's easy when using structured SCSS rules to have button.scss file and include the rules to parent this way:

```
//my-skin/button.scss
.button {...}

//my-second-skin/button.scss
.button {...}

//main.scss
.my-skin {
    @import my-skin/button.scss
}

.my-second-skin {
    @import my-second-skin/button.scss
}

//output.css
.my-skin .button {...}
.my-second-skin .button {...}
```

Problem occurs when prepended nested rules are used in skin files:

```
//my-skin/button.scss
.button {
    .test & {...}
}

//main.scss
.my-skin {
    @import my-skin/button.scss
}

//produced output.css
.test .my-skin .button {...}
```

Is there any way to produce this kind of output using directly SCSS without any post-processing? Thank you

```
//desired output.css
.my-skin .test .button {...}
```